# Background Images not showing on Github Pages for Website

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

I've looked at some other threads on Stack Overflow regarding this problem, but for some reason they don't seem to be working. I've checked things like the path directory for the image, and I think that it's correct.
   Here's a link to my repo for the website on github pages: https://github.com/lawrencecheng123/lawrencecheng123.github.io

In my repo there is a "Seattle.jpg" image that I'm trying to set as the background of the first page of my website, which is referenced by the "fstPage" class on line 81 of the "index.html" file and line 321 of the "index.css" file in the repo.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It fails because you named your file wrong. Inside of your index.css, you wanted to use a file named `Seattle.JPG`.

Your file is named `Seattle.jpg`. Fix the ending and add `https://`.

Here's the right link: `https://lawrencecheng123.github.io/Seattle.jpg`

---

Complete CSS:

```
.fstPage {
    background-image:url("https://lawrencecheng123.github.io/Seattle.jpg");
    /*background-color: lightgray;*/
    height: 700px;
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

---

Working snippet:

```css
.fstPage  {
    background-image:url("https://lawrencecheng123.github.io/Seattle.jpg");
    /*background-color: lightgray;*/
    height: 700px;
    width:100%;
    background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="fstPage"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did that before for the link, but it still wouldn't load. I also read on a different thread that using .JPG would work, so I was trying that way too. However, for both ways it just shows a white page for me

Comment: Did you include `index.css`? Can't see it in your `index.html`.

Comment: Thank you for the snippet. It seems to be working in there. However, when I put it into the main file it still shows up as blank for some reason.

Comment: I put the new link with the https into the fstPage class in index.css, and I also have the fstPage in index.html as well. Not entirely sure why it works in the snippet, but not in my main code

Comment: Looks like you don't include your `index.css`. Try to add `<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">` in your head.

Comment: Actually nevermind, it's showing up now. Thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 0):

first import index.css file in your index.html file like

change (1) :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
```

and  then you have to update your class as mentioned below

change(2):

```
.fstPage {
            background-image:url("Seattle.jpg");
            /*background-color: lightgray;*/
            height: 700px;
            width:100%;
            background-size:cover;
        }
```

and I hope it will work fine for you also

Comment: @Lawrence Cheng

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for all the forums. But none of which worked for me.
Only workaround for me was to change the order of `stylesheets` in the `head`

I mean , if you are using multiple stylesheets, including those from bootstrap cdn with the locally saved one, always keep the local stylesheet on top.

Like this

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/yourcode.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
```