# Background image not showing up on my github.io

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

So if you run my code in your editor in default browser the background image appears, but ever since i made it an .io on github, no image is showing up in the background.

Does anyone understand why?! Thanks for any feedback!

[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVE2v.jpg)

[Whats happening on my .io!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU4Fa.jpg)

Help!!!!!

Thanks!

https://github.com/Joeyryanbridges/lindseyStyle (github code)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Background Images not showing on Github Pages for Website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41607049/background-images-not-showing-on-github-pages-for-website)

Comment: check console for errors. if error shows image is not found. try to change the image link to its root path by adding ~ ex: `<img class="linlin" src="~/assets/images/lin2.jpg" alt="lindsey">`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Stack Overflow, Looks like the image path and css background shorthand is wrong.

```
.centerImg{background: url('../images/succ2.png') no-repeat center fixed ghostwhite; 
background-size: 56%;}
```

Let me know it works for you.