# on my github pages website the images wont load. does any one know why? this is the website

Tags: html, css, github, github-pages

so I have been working on my website for a few months now and the background image won't load.

This is what the CSS code looks like:

```css
.main{
  width: 100%;
  background: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5)50%,rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5)50%), url(file:///home/g7adz177a/Downloads/website%20background.png);
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 109vh;
}
```

I expected it to work on GitHub pages because when I opened the HTML file, it worked on the browser.

https://avrydacool1.github.io/avrysartshow.github.io/ (the website)

Comment: As an aside, you have an anchor element within a button element which is not 'legal' HTML. You could put your code through a validator to uncover such problems. As for the image, itseems as though you are trying to load an image from  your local system which isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your background image seems to be loading now (you have embedded in the style sheet with [commit e789643](https://github.com/AvryDaCool1/avrysartshow.github.io/commit/e789643d0f067378a083b19b82a6c4cf75591ffb)), probably because the previous `url` was not supported:

```
 url(https://github.com/AvryDaCool1/avrysartshow.github.io/blob/main/website%20background.png);
```

What might have worked is (as [illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41607164/6309)):

```
 url(https://avrydacool1.github.io/avrysartshow.github.io/website%20background.png);
```